# Last activity = greater than 30 days

Tags: reporting

Good morning, is it possible in SFDC reports to create a filter that shows "last activity" = "greater than 30 days" rather than the standard "greater than" specific date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the report filter criteria

1. Pick the field
2. Set to Less Than
3. Set to "LAST 30 DAYS" (minus the quotes)

[image]

This will get all records that have a last activity that is greater than 30 days ago

If you want all that have Activity **IN** the last 30 days, simply change the equality to **Equals**